# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException when running MVC codefirst application on different computer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application using the Code first approach.  It works great on the computer I originally created the project on.  Then I pushed the entire application to GitHub and cloned onto a different computer.

The application starts fine, but when I try to navigate to a page that displays information from the database, I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

Digging into the problem points me to something wrong with the connection string, but I can't for the life of me see what the problem is.  Can someone please help?

Here is my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDemo" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MyDemo.Models.My_DBContext;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Not sure where else to look.

Comment: Please provide SQL exception message detail.

Comment: Its probably the database is not getting created or data source is not accessible

Comment: Here is the detail:{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)"}

Answer (score 0):

Is your database getting created? If not try the `Update-Database`-command in your packet manager console.

Maybe LocalDb isn't installed, make sure the correct Sql Server is installed.

**Edit**: As the Exception tells you, make sure the correct version of Sql Server is installed or change your connectionstring to the value you use in Sql Managment Studio.

Comment: How do I know if the database is getting created?  It does not look like it is...

Comment: What version of Sql Server do you have installed?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check the Sql Server version?

Comment: Good question, I have no idea. When you connect to a server using Sql Server Management Studio, are you able to connect to `.` or `./SqlExpress`?

Comment: I don't have Sql Server Management Studio...I just downloaded Visual Studio Community 2015.  When I look in the server explorer I can see the database, so it is trying to create it.  When I right mouse click the database in the server explorer and select "Modify Connection" it looks the same as it does on the other computer.  But when I click "Test Connection" I get the same exception as above.   ps.  Thx for your help.

Comment: Also, under the "Log on to the server" heading, "Use Windows Authentication" is selected, as opposed to "Use SQL Server Authentication"

Comment: Windows authentication is fine. You can download SQL Server here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx.